# Do I need to create a separate glossary item to create a hyperlinked \gls for the plural form?

Tags: glossaries, plural

Is there a way to have a single glossary entry where I can use the \gls command to thus hyperlink the *plural* form of a noun?

Below I've included a MWE of a glossary with two entries: a singular form of 'metric' as well as the *plural* form 'metric**s**'.

If I comment out the second, *plural* glossary entry for 'metric**s**', then I get the error:

```
Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `metric**s**' has not been defined.
```

Apparently, it is not enough to simply specify `plural={metrics}` in order to use \gls to create a hyperlink to the *plural* form of 'metric'.

Is there a way that in just ONE glossary entry for 'metric', I can specify both the singular AND *plural* form of 'metric' and ***then*** be able to issue BOTH the \gls{metric} and \gls{metric**s**} commands without generating an error?

This is not a huge issue. I'd just like to know there is some way I can streamline my glossary by reducing the second entries I currently have for all the plural noun forms.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

        \newglossaryentry{metric}{
        name={metric},
        description={A measure for something; a means of deriving a quantitative measurement or approximation for otherwise qualitative phenomena (especially used in engineering)[1]},
        plural={metrics},
        descriptionplural={plural for metric},
        sort={metric}}

% \begin{comment}   % If I remove both '%'s to restore both comment lines, an error occurs.
        \newglossaryentry{metrics}{
        name={metrics},
        description={(plural for metric)},
        sort={metrics}}
% \end{comment}

\begin{document}

Singular: \glsdesc{metric}. \par

Plural: \glspl{metric}. \par

Plural: \gls{metrics}. \par

Plural: \glsdesc{metrics}. \par

\printglossaries

[1] metric. (2021, May 10). \textit{Wiktionary, The Free Dictionary}. Retrieved 20:25, July 15, 2021 from \url{https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=metric&oldid=62505762}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You COULD hypothetically define a new `\gls` command that would check the last letter of the input; if that letter is not 's', then it would call the old `\gls` if it is, it would call `\glspl` with everything in the input up to the last letter. That could take SOME time as you would have to account for entries that end with 's' but are not plural(!). Alternatively, you could go through your document with search and replace and replace all instances of `\gls{metrics}` with `\glspl{metric}` I guarantee that would take LESS time.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround ... there are, of course, those nouns that I did not use in the MWE that don't just add an S for the plural ... like potato and potatoes or flux and fluxes ... which I thought about using to show why I was hoping that \newglossaryentry has some sort of mysterious 'trap door' that in some way would magically allow for, or accommodate, a call to \gls for the plural form. That is the kind of thing that brings all of us here ... Thanks again!